# How to hide empty dropdown bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Cerca" autocomplete="off" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" />
            <div class="dropdown-menu w-75" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
            </div>
```

I have an empty dropdown but when I click into the input the dropdown still appear.

Comment: i tried to put your code in the fiddle, and dropdown doesn't appear.

Comment: Well, that's not what happen in my project. I tried to put the code in the fiddle and happened as you said

Comment: Frid posta tutto il codice su uno snippet.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini la parte interessata era solo quella che ho postato. Un semplice dropdown vuoto caricato su un progetto laravel, magari quest'ultimo potrebbe causarne questo problema? Cosa ne pensi?